# Trying to get rid of an alert "Cookie set without HttpOnly Flag"

Tags: php, html, cookies

EDIT: I changed the code to reflect changes however the window will still not load, any advice? I Added "session_set_cookie_params"
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"

I keep getting the alert "Cookie set without HttpOnly Flag" I have looked up different sources but nothing seems to give me a definite answer. The following is my code:

```
    <html>

<?php 
session_set_cookie_params
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"
header ("X-Frame-Options: DENY"); 
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
?>

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>User Authenticate </title>
</head>
<body> 

<?php

    // Retrieve Post Data
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["emailadd"];


         // Set the session information
         session_start();  
         $_SESSION['appusername'] = $username; 
         $_SESSION['appemail'] = $email;
$newusername = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ===false) {  
    echo "<h3> Session Data  </h3>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>
            <td>Username </td>
            <td> Email </td>
             </tr>";
    echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $_SESSION['appusername'] . "</td>";
    echo  "<td>" . $_SESSION['appemail']. "</td>";
    echo   "</tr>";     
    echo "</table>";      

// Provide a button to logout

echo "<form name='logout' method='post' action='logout.php'> 
<input name='btnsubmit' type='submit' value='Logout'> 
</form>";

} else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}        


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding "Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"" but this just made it so my page would not load. I am using the ZAP Vulnerability Tool to find possible vulnerabilities on a web page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting that alert from?

Comment: I am using a software called ZAP, it's a web vulnerability tool

Comment: Use `session_set_cookie_params` to enable the `httponly` option for the session cookie. See the documentation.

Comment: Ok, one other question, where do I find the documentation cause I am in a class for this and all the reading refers to a website and no real manuals?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: Either type `session_set_cookie_params` in Google or load `http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params` in your browser.